# convert html, css and icons to pdf using itextsharp dotnet core2.1

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, itext, itext7

i am trying to convert html (with css and icons) into pdf using itextsharp but couldn't make it work could anyone tell me what's wrong in this code.

i am using dotnet core 2.1

```
public static void pdf() {
            byte[] pdf; // result will be here

            var cssText = File.ReadAllText(@"./css/main.css");
            var html = File.ReadAllText(@"./index.html");

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 60, 60);
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                document.Open();

                using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
                {
                    using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
                    {
                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                    }
                }

                document.Close();

                pdf = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"./2.pdf", pdf);
        }
```

getting below error

```
"Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.",
```

Comment: With "Activator.CreateInstance" it may be an issue with Dependency Injection. I assume this is in "XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance()"? On what OS are you trying to run this?

Comment: i am using winsows 10